# My search bar do not want make any transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, github

i want to ask and make a help for my code.
In my vue code, i want to make seacrh bar like github.

like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lb0j.png)

to this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHnDD.png)

but my css transition not work well. the searcbar do not want grow up when i clicked or move to the seacrbar.

this is the code

```html
<template>
  <section class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <div @click="isVisible = !isVisible" class="selected-item">
      <!-- <span v-if="selectedItem">{{ selectedItem.name }}</span> -->
      <!-- <span v-else>Select User</span> -->
      <input type="text" v-model="searchQuery" class="input-nav" />
      <span :class="isVisible ? 'dropdown' : ''" class="drop-down-icon">+</span>
    </div>
    <div :class="isVisible ? 'visible' : 'invisible'" class="dropdown-popover">
      <span v-if="filteredUser.length === 0"> No Data</span>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li
            @click="selectItem(user)"
            v-for="user in filteredUser"
            :key="user.id"
          >
            <router-link :to="'/detail/' + user.name">{{
              user.name
            }}</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Navbar1",
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: "",
      selectedItem: null,
      isVisible: false,
      userArray: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUser() {
      const query = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
      if (this.searchQuery === "") {
        return this.userArray;
      }
      return this.userArray.filter((user) => {
        return Object.values(user).some((word) =>
          String(word).toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
      });
    },
  },
  methods: {
    selectItem(user) {
      this.selectedItem = user;
      this.isVisible = false;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.github.com/users/dimaswntech/repos", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "token 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",
        },
        owner: "dimaswntech",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.userArray = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.dropdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .selected-item {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .selected-item .drop-down-icon {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .selected-item .drop-down-icon.dropdows {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid white;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover.visible {
  max-height: 450px;
  visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover input {
  width: 272px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover input:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 542px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover .options {
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover .options ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover .options ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #b49c9c;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.dropdown-wrapper .dropdown-popover .options ul li:hover {
  background: #43838b;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}


</style>
```

can you help me to make search bar can do a transition like searchbar on github.

Comment: your executable snippet fails to run

Comment: The snippet won't work, you have to configure it to use vue, and axios.